# assign value to pointer that points to array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have an array of int pointers

```
int * arr[3];
```

If I want to define a pointer to `arr`, I can do the following:

```
int * (*p)[] = &arr;
```

However, in my code, I need to first declare that pointer:

```
int *(*p)[];
```

My question is, how to assign `&arr` to it after it has been declared. I have tried `(*p)[] = &arr;` but that didn't work.

Comment: You might have to include a code example and show what exactly that didn't work. `(int* (*)[]` is a pointer to incomplete array type, so that can be an issue in some contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do `p = &arr`.

Try [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nc7n63rY5).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign p to arr you simply have to do p = &arr;
this is because when you write p you basically are saying to C: this is the pointer to a array of pointers

So when you &arr you get the same type as & gives you the pointer to the variable next to it

Also beware that if you want the value of a variable inside a struct that its pointed to( ie struct something *a, where inside there int i) you put a -> (making it a a->integer;)

You should update the answer to the full extent